# Difference in behaviour of pow from math.h for same input

Tags: c++

I am using Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 with default compiler as provided in Dev C++ options. Consider the following two programs:

First:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    cout <<(int)pow (10,2);    //100
    return 0;
}
```

Second:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int k = 2;
    cout <<(int)pow (10,k);    //99
    return 0;
}
```

Is that a bug in implicit coercion from `int` to datatype of arument of called `pow` in the compiler shipped with Dev C++ 4.9.9.2? OR is that an expected behaviour? Exactly which version of `pow` is called (I tried to debug but was unable to locate called one)?

Note : If we replace **math.h** by **cmath**, the program does not compile with a warning of *ambiguous call to pow* (seems a better condition). Also on newer version of Dev C++ on the same system, the output is correct in both programs.

> **Edit1** : I don't think that my question is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os) as I am giving same input but getting different result. **2** and **k** both are integers.
>
> **Edit2 : I feel that people are less interested in understanding my question than seeing my rep. That's why they marked the question as a duplicate. They don't bother that I am giving the same inputs in different ways but getting different results.**

Comment: Looks like dev c++ 4.9.9.2 was released in 2005, who cares about its strange bugs, use the newer one :)

Comment: If you closely see the result of `pow` (as it is a `double` value), the double value is usually not stored as it is, an approximation is stored. So the value returned might be 99.9999999999998 or something like that, which when you convert to `int` leaves you with only `99`.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad why did it not happen in the case I passed **2** to `pow` for second parameter.

Comment: [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704195/995714)

Comment: probably because one is the builtin version of gcc and one is the pow function from stdlib

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Regarding the warning, are you aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24749982/4944425)? The same may hold for your question, it looks like your compiler chooses different overloads for literals and variables when <math.h> is included.

Comment: @Bob__ I understand that. I just want a reference.